# Assigning accumulating numbers to events along a (river)network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, network, hydrology, events

I have a river network along which there are lake polygons that I want to assign orders to. So from headwaters to downstream I want the order to increase depending on the number of previous lakes.

As of now I have the network in both route and geometric network form and made route events of the lakes, however I can't sort out how to assign the accumulating order to the events.

[image: lakeorder]

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned *routes* and *events* which suggest you are seeking a solution using linear referencing? I would take the centroid of each lake and locate these along your route. This will create your event distance along route, that is your order. Sort the resulting table by distance along route then add another field and create an incremental number.

Comment: I like the idea but it won't give the desired result if there's branching in the network.

http://imgur.com/on23XvZ

Comment: And the solution doesn't necessarily have to be in linear referencing. I just went on that track because I thought the event table tool would be enough. Anything that will do the job automatically would be wonderful. I'm starting to worry that I might have to cough up some script that will locate the starting points of the branches and move with the FROM-TO in the network adding +1 every time it comes across sections marked as an event. Problem is I don't have much experience writing that sort of script.

Comment: [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Findallsitesupstreamofasite.html) has a tool that would generate the table that you could then aggregate, suggest you explore that?

Comment: RivEX looks really cool. Are you the dev? I think using the Shreve order along with the Upstream tool might be just as precise as I could hope for. Thanks :)

Comment: I am the developer behind RivEX and can provide support if required.